# Should proactive caching be used instead of processing dimensions?

Tags: ssis, ssas-2008

I am confused about best practice for updating cube data throughout the day.  We have a small order processing environment, where I would like to update a dashboard containing Order statuses.  I am able to get this to work by creating an SSIS package and scheduling it to run every 4 minutes.  This works.

But when I disable the SSIS job above, and instead turn on Real-time ROLAP on all the dimensions and the Cube, nothing ever changes in dashboard.  Do I misunderstand the purpose of proactive caching?

I'm using SQL Server standard containing our production data, but our Analysis Server is Enterprise, in case that makes a difference. I'd also be willing to use Automatic or Scheduled MOLAP if that works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

no, you did not. I think you have configuration issues.

I assume the job you disabled was coping data from your database to your data warehouse, right?
And your cube reads from your data warehouse, right?

so now, your OLAP database is being updated (by your application) but the changes are not being pushed to the cube (because the job is off)

Proactive caching (specially with ROLAP) is a way to get your data live without having to schedule a cube refresh for every x minutes. But the job that populates your DW must still be running.

I can guess that the package you disabled was, besides updating the DW, also refreshing the cube. Check it's source.

Comment: You seem to be right on all accounts.  The job I disabled does nothing except process the cube.  Should it do more than that?  Are you saying that I should have it running, in addition to the ROLAP?   I can address these issue later if necessary, thanks.

Comment: no no, If you are using ROLAP in all your cube you don't need a job to refresh it.
I imagined that your job also updated your DW. Is the cube connecting to the same DB that your OLTP application?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  The cube's dimensions are retrieving data from DSVs that get data from the order system database (mainly from Views). Is that what you mean?  The cube itself and the dimensions are on a different server.  Is this not the standard configuration?

Comment: I just noticed that proactive caching was not turned on under the dimensions branch of the tree on the Analysis Server.  I turned it on in the Cubes section only.  Maybe that is the problem.

Comment: what I mean is that you shouldn't have your OLAP cube querying the same database as your "order system database", its not considered "best practice". You should have a DW so the cube can access data from it.